# How to connect to hive via CLI on cloudera

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera

We are running CDH 4.1.1 from the HUE / Beeswax Hive is runng fine and /beeswax/tables shows all tables.

I want to use the hive CLI to list all tables:

```
overlord@overlord-datanode1:~$ hive
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j.properties
Hive history file=/tmp/overlord/hive_job_log_overlord_201211280646_1426149164.txt
hive> SHOW TABLES;
OK
Time taken: 0.071 seconds
```

This appears to be empty, which leads me to believe that I'm maybe connecting to the wrong hive metastore?

How can I access the same hive data as from HUE/beeswax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason is hive cli and beehive is using 2 different users(with different previlage) so when you switch users Meta store switch automatically(if it does not exist already).

If you are using derby as your metastore i would suggest you to migrated it to Mysql or PostgreSQL as derby is not suitable for production.
to migrate follow these guides.

```
http://www.mazsoft.com/blog/post/2010/02/01/Setting-up-HadoopHive-to-use-MySQL-as-metastore.aspx

https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/Hive+Installation
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have an idea as which user the beeswax/hue would be running? I think that it's already the same user that I try to run the command line from, but I'd like to confirm. Also is there any way to get info about the meta store it is connected to or anything like that?

Comment: In the cloudera user mailing list I found the answer:
https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/d/msg/cdh-user/e02lgCPdrAs/R4yrG2DNm-MJ: "This is probably because the DB used for the meta store is Derby (and only allow one user concurrently). Can you change the Hive Metastore DB to be MySql instead: https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/Hive+Installation#HiveInstallation-UsingtheEmbeddedMetaStore%28Derby%29"